# AJAX POST results in 404 error when calling VB.NET Web Service

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, web-services, http-status-code-404

I am trying to build a jquery plug in that hits a VB.NET web service with an AJAX POST request. For right now **I want to stand up the request to send JSON and then receive it back in the console.log.** I had it working then i changed the naming conventions around and I keep getting a 404 Error now. i have posted the entire web.config file here in case it could be that. Just send the data hit the web service and then have the same data come back into the console. Here is my code so far:

JS:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.loadMGMT = function(options) {
        $this = $(this);
        data = $.extend({
            level: 'ORA',
            titles: 'Administrator'
        }, options );
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            url: '/webapps/webservices/Intranet/getActiveDirectoryInfo.aspx/leadership',
            data: "{leader:" + JSON.stringify(data) + "}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(api){
            console.log(api);
        });
    };  
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#leaders').loadMGMT({
        level: "DORA",
        titles: 'Regional Administrator'
    });
});
```

Web Service:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Class VB
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function leadership(ByVal leader As Leader) As Leader
        Return leader
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Leader
    Private _level As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _level
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _level = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _titles As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _titles
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _titles = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vx.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true" userName="NRCDOMAIN\r2cfsvc" password="LkE^ehf~UXk~JAPf"/>

        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following, it's not easy to find people using VB these days!

My code also handles the CORS problem, the html can be hosted in www.a.com (or as a native app in android or iphone), and the web services can be hosted in www.b.com

1. Create a blank solution in VS 2015 Community or VS 2013 Community Update 4 with Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.1
2. Create a blank JavaScript Cordova Project in the solution.
3. Replace the index.html with the following code:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> function funCheckWS() {
>     var tblLogin = {};
>     tblLogin.ReturnCode = "0000";
>     jQuery.support.cors = true;
>     $.ajax({
>         type: 'POST',
>         url: 'http://localhost:8080/wsMain.asmx/funCheckWS',
>         data: "{tblLogin:" + JSON.stringify(tblLogin) + "}",
>         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
>         dataType: 'json',
>         crossDomain: true,
>         async: false,
>         success: function (r) {
>
> tblLogin.ReturnCode = r.d.ReturnCode;
>
> alert("Return Code from Web Services:" + tblLogin.ReturnCode);
>
>         },
>
>         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
>             // Browser does not support WS
>             //alert(xhr.status);
>             //alert(thrownError);
>         }
>     });
> }    </script>
> </head>
> <body>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

4. Create a Visual Basic "Asp.Net Web Application", the following refer to this project:
5. In Web.config, add the following inside

> ```
> <webServices>
>       <protocols>
>         <add name="HttpGet"/>
>         <add name="HttpPost"/>
>       </protocols>
> </webServices>
> ```

6. In Web.config, add the following inside

> ```
> <httpProtocol>
>    <customHeaders>
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,OPTIONS,GET"/>
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With,Accept"/>
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
>    </customHeaders>
> </httpProtocol>
> ```

7. In the project, add a new VB Class named clsTable.vb, with the following code:

> ```
> Public Class tabLogin
>     Private _ReturnCode As String
>     Public Property ReturnCode As String
>         Get
>             Return _ReturnCode
>         End Get
>         Set(ByVal value As String)
>             _ReturnCode = value
>         End Set
>     End Property
> End Class
> ```

8. In the project, add a new item "Visual Basic Web Services (ASMX)" and name it wsMain.asmx with the following code:

> ```
> Imports System.Web.Services
> Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
> Imports System.ComponentModel
> Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
> Imports System.Web.Script.Services
> Imports System
> Imports System.Collections.Generic
> Imports System.Linq
> Imports System.Web
>
> <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
> <System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
> <System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
> <ToolboxItem(False)> _
> Public Class wsMain
>     Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
>
>     Private tblLogin As tabLogin
>     <WebMethod()> _
>     <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
>     Public Function funCheckWS(tblLogin As tabLogin) As tabLogin
>         tblLogin.ReturnCode = "0001"
>         Return tblLogin
>     End Function
>
> End Class
> ```

9. Build this project and use IIS to host it using port 8080.
10. build the javascript cordova project and deploy it to a mobile phone or just host the index.html in the IIS using whatever port you like, for example 8070.
11. In the mobile phone, run the app.  OR in any desktop browser, open the index.html by using http://localhost:8070/index.html
12. Then a message box appears with ReturnCode = "0001", which is returned from the web services.